# How can I integrate a textbox inside a CachedNetworkImage Widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

any idea how I can integrate the yellow textbox inside a CachedNetworkImage Widget ?
[image]

Here the code:

```
return ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: imgUrl,
          placeholder: (context, url) => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
          width: 250,
          height: 160,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        ),
      );
```

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the image sized is fixed I am using `Container` with `clipBehavior`.

```dart
Container buildItem(String imgUrl) {
    return Container(
      width: 250,
      height: 160,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, // you can use SizedBox with ClipRRect
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            /// even though it will fill by default
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: imgUrl,
              placeholder: (context, url) =>
                  const CircularProgressIndicator(),
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 0,
            bottom: 16,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft:
                          Radius.circular(16) // modify the based on your need
                      )),
              child: Text("Text"),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

More about [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

PS: While other's answer doesn't clarify the positioning, I'm posting this.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not, you have to use `stack` widget

```
    Stack(
       children: [
      ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: imgUrl,
          placeholder: (context, url) => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
          width: 250,
          height: 160,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        ),
      ),
Text("3$")//here will be your text widget you can decorate with container  
       ]
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html